# Python3: Distance between rectangles keep changing

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

Creating rectangles with equal distance between them but with random heights and widths. However the distance between them is not fixed and changes.

```
    import TurtleHelper
    import turtle
    import random as rd


    def drawRectangle(myTurtle, width, height): 
        for i in range(2):
            myTurtle.fd(width)
            myTurtle.left(90)
            myTurtle.fd(height)
            myTurtle.left(90)

    def drawRectangleagain(myTurtle):       
        myTurtle.up()
        myTurtle.forward(100)
        myTurtle.down()





def main():
    window=TurtleHelper.initWindow()
    t=turtle.Turtle()
    t.pencolor("blue")



    for i in range(3):
        drawRectangle(t,rd.randint(20, 60), rd.randint(20, 110))
        drawRectangleagain(t)


    window.exitonclick()
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rectangle ABCD]

You're starting at vertex D, and ending at vertex D. So when you move forward 100, the distance between one rectangle and the next is `100 - DC`. Since DC is a random number, the distance between the rectangles is a random number.

You can get consistent spacing as follows

```
def drawRectangle(myTurtle, width, height): 
        for i in range(2):
            myTurtle.fd(width)
            myTurtle.left(90)
            myTurtle.fd(height)
            myTurtle.left(90)
        myTurtle.up()
        myTurtle.fd(width)
```